# How can I use .NET4's BigInteger with GPUs or FPGAs? Do I handle big-endian math?

Tags: c#, opencl, gpu, biginteger, endianness

**Part 1**

I'm interested in offloading [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) calculations to GPUs or FPGAs.  Is it possible to do math operations (exponents, etc) on something other than a CPU with this type? (or objects that consume this datatype?

**Part 2**

Since BigInteger on .NET is small endian and I'm not sure if that means it's exclusive to the CPU since all GPU based code I've seen is Bigendian.

- If it is possible to use on a GPU/FPGA, must I manage the endian-order of things?

Comment: Yes, and no. But arbitrary precision arithmetic is difficult to do on GPU's since they do not have dynamic memory allocation, so you need to set a maximum size of some kind. Endianness is irrelevant.